# How can the overall SQALE rating for a service be A when all the components are B/C rated?

Tags: sonarqube, technical-debt

The overall SQALE Rating for my service is A, however the components have the same as B or C. It doesn't add up. Please suggest.

Comment: _Every single one_ of your components has a B or C? _Every one of them_?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Yes, not even one has an A rating, still the overall rating is A.

Answer (score 0):

The SQALE rating is essentially a ratio of the size of your code base versus  the estimated time to fix all issues in the project.

This A / not-A discrepancy can only be caused by rounding.

Specifically, as described in the [docs of the deprecated SQALE plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SQALE+Plugin#SQALEPlugin-UnderstandingSQALERatings)

> The SQALE density formula is:
>
> `Remediation cost / Development cost`
>
> Which can be restated as:
>
> `Remediation cost / (Cost to develop 1 line of code * Number of lines of code)`
>
> ...
>
> The default SQALE rating axis is:
> A=0-0.1, B=0.11-0.2, C=0.21-0.5, D=0.51-1

Comment: Thanks but what do we mean by rounding here?